# Azure Devops Server M170 - YAML Pipelines "Stages to Run"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

i am using Azure Devops Server 2020 (M170) and in Run Pipeline there are no option for select "Stages to Run". It was anounced in M162 but still not working on M170, is it moved to never version or? I have not menu point "Stages to Run" totally....

Tried to research versions, but have no result. Tried to make hardcoded stages, have stages but still no "Stages to Run" menu...

[image: Screenshot of existing menu point]

Comment: What is announced for Azure DevOps Service isn't a good indication for when it will be available on the Server. Unfortunately. Your server is a couple of update packs behind (latest is M193), I'm not sure whether the feature got introduced on the Server in any of these though.

Comment: With Azure DevOps Server 2022 now available, it's your greatest chance to gaining this feature.

Comment: @jessehouwing are you sure that it's available in 2022 ?

Comment: No, i haven't confirmed that. But you can easily download the Azure DevOps Server 2022 installer and install it on a VM or your personal workstation in a few clicks to confirm.